# Sed - How to Print Regex Groups in Multi-Line?

Tags: regex, linux, sed, multiline, regex-group

Input file (test):

```
123456<a id="id1" name="name1" href="link1">This is link1</a>789<a id="id2"
href="link2">This is link2</a>0123
```

Desired output:

```
link1
link2
```

What I have done:

```
$ sed -e '/<a/{:begin;/<\/a>/!{N;b begin};s/<a\([^<]*\)<\/a>/QQ/;/<a/b begin}' test
123456QQ789QQ0123
```

Question: How do you print the regex groups in sed (**multiline**)?

Comment: Does it have to be with `sed`?

Comment: Sed can't make it? Looks a common quesiton.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use sed like this:

```
sed -e '/<a/{:begin;/<\/a>/!{N;b begin};s/<a\([^<]*\)<\/a>/\n/;/<a/b begin}'
```

then it will print in different lines:

```
123456
789
0123
```

But is this what you are trying to print? Or you want to print text in hrefs?

#### Update 1: To get hrefs between well formed `<a` and `</a>`

```
sed -r '$!N; s~\n~~; s~(<a )~\n\1~ig; s~[^<]*<a[^>]*href\s*=\s*"([^"]*)"[^\n]*~\1\n~ig' test
```

**output**

```
link1
link2
```

#### Update 2: Getting above output using bash regex feature

```
regex='href="([^"]*)"'
while read line; do
   [[ $line =~ $regex ]] || continue
   echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
done < test
```

**output**

```
link1
link2
```

Comment: @anubhava thx, I want to print the **text in href** out of <a> link.

Comment: @anubhava still in trouble, there is a "\n" before link2 href in the test. Have you missed the \n? thanks very much

Comment: thanks, @anubhava It worked at last. But the way still uses \1 to replace the regex matching text. Is there a way just to print the groups?

Comment: Please check my update2 section above for printing just the captured groups using BASH. However I think in sed there is no straightforward way of doing exactly that.

Comment: Yes, update2 can handle the example line by line. but if href=\n"link2", there will be a problem. So BASH and Sed are not good at parsing HTMLs.